# How to save sort order back to the server with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say we have an ordered list of Todo items, the top one is the one we'll work on next:

```
App.TodoItem = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("string")
});

// comes back ordered from the server
var todos = App.TodoItem.find()
```

We then re-order the list via a drag & drop interface.

The API has an endpoint of `/todos/sort` which expects to be posted an array of IDs in their new order. This can be changed, but it's what we've got right now.

How would you go about saving the new order to the server?

I suppose I could add in a `position` attribute and update that on all the items when the order changes, then call `commit` on the store - but that will send all the data over the wire when all we want is the new ordering. Plus it would send lots of requests unless we implement batch saving.

Currently I'm thinking of bypassing Ember-Data for this part entirely and just have a plain old `$.ajax` request in a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Create a model `TodoList` that contains metadata about the todos. One (i guess for now the only) attribute of that model would be the positions array. So when a user orders the list of todos there is no need to update each todos but instead update the container.